# Display routes in a view/controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've written an API in Ruby on Rails and I want to have one page that lists all of the routes available (I know this can be done through the command line using `rake routes`).

I want to generate this automatically rather than having to update it myself whenever I update the code. Is there a way to get a list of all of the routes in a controller (or a view)?

Comment: +1 I am looking for this question with correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

I started to explore the solution given by jvnill and found in the docs it stated that RouteInspector [should not be used](http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Application/RouteInspector). For what reason I don't know, but I decided to have a look at the code so and try and get a more useful output rather than just strings. I used the code by jvnill as a starting point.

```
all_routes = Rails.application.routes.routes
routes = all_routes.routes.collect do | route |
  reqs = route.requirements

  controller = reqs[:controller] || ':controller'
  action = reqs[:action] || ':action'

  constraints = reqs.except(:controller, :action)

  verb = route.verb.source.gsub(/[$^]/, '')

  {name: route.name.to_s, verb: verb, path: route.path.spec.to_s, reqs: reqs}

end

routes.reject! { |r| r[:path].starts_with?("/rails/info/properties") || r[:path] == "#{Rails.application.config.assets.prefix}" }
```

`routes` then contains a hash containing the name of the route, path and the controller and action.

Comment: Good one Chris. Sorry for late reply. I was out of station. I tried your code and still got a same page.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at how the rake task for rake routes is implemented :)  It is found in the railties gem inside `lib/rails/tasks/routes.rake`.  But to make it easier, here it is

```
task :routes => :environment do
  Rails.application.reload_routes!
  all_routes = Rails.application.routes.routes

  require 'rails/application/route_inspector'
  inspector = Rails::Application::RouteInspector.new
  puts inspector.format(all_routes, ENV['CONTROLLER']).join "\n"
end
```

Comment: @chrisbulmer Hi. i am a newbie and looking for explained answer for this. How did you manage to create a separate page to list all routes?

Comment: @Vinay Created a new controller and action (use rails g controller routes show) then added a route for it in the routes file. I added the 3rd line in the answer above in the controller but put an @ symbol in front of the variable and in the view I put the final three lines before then end between '<%' tags

Comment: @Chrisbulmer Hi, is the `<%` tag should be `<%=` or what?

Comment: Sorry, should have been <%=

Comment: I got this error in the page `false #<Rails::Application::RouteInspector:0x6fc0acfb>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27114/discussion-between-vinay-and-chrisbulmer)

Comment: Rails 4 has this built in, as the page you describe is rendered whenever there is a routing error. Perhaps looking at the source code for that on Github could give some insight.